# Play audio file in sequence in Swift, where the second sound gets played on repeat

Tags: ios, swift, audio

For the background music in my game, I would like to play two sounds. The first sound gets played only once at the beginning (4 bar intro). Following that, the second sound (main music) gets played on an endless loop. The code below unfortunately plays the sounds simultaneously, instead of in sequence (when I looked into AVQueuePlayer, I wasn't able to figure out how to loop only the second of the two sounds):

```
var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
var backgroundMusicPlayerIntro: AVAudioPlayer!

func playBackgroundMusic(filename: String, withIntro intro: String) {
    let resourceUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    let resourceUrlIntro = Bundle.main.url(forResource: intro, withExtension: nil)

    guard let url = resourceUrl, let urlIntro = resourceUrlIntro else {
        print("Could not find files: \(intro) and/or \(filename)")
        return
    }

    //play the intro first before playing the main loop
    do {
        try backgroundMusicPlayerIntro = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urlIntro)
        backgroundMusicPlayerIntro.numberOfLoops = 1
        backgroundMusicPlayerIntro.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayerIntro.play()
    } catch {
        print("Could not create audio player!")
        return
    }

    //main music that gets played on repeat
    do {
        try backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        backgroundMusicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayer.play()
    } catch {
        print("Could not create audio player!")
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: "when I looked into AVQueuePlayer, I wasn't able to figure out how to loop only the second of the two sounds" Nevertheless, that is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting 2 players at the same time. You can use one player property, and it's `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` can play the second sound when the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` method is called at the end of the first sound. Basically something like this:

```
class Player: AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    func startPlayingFirstSong() {
        // your 1st do/catch code...
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: urlIntro)
        audioPlayer?.delegate = self
    }

    // AVAudioPlayer will call this func when the first song ends:
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {
        // your 2nd do/catch code...
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        audioPlayer?.delegate = self
    }

}

let player = Player()
player.startPlayingFirstSong()
```

Comment: How would I implement audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method (within this method, do I include the code to play the second sound?) Then, how would I call audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying after the intro is done playing?